# Error metadata-generation-failed

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Cuando intento installa psycopg2 me generar este error[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya intente con pip install psycopg2 y pip install psycopg2 --pre y sigue el mismo error, mi version de python es 3.10.9

Comment: Tienes las bibliotecas de desarrollo de PostgreSQL instaladas? dime que sistema operativo tienes

Comment: @infinit3Loop__ cuales son las bibliotecas? tengo mac

Comment: No pongas fotos, pon el texto. La foto no se lee.

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje de error que te aparece indica que faltan archivos de encabezado para la biblioteca libpq, que es la biblioteca cliente de PostgreSQL, estos archivos de encabezado son necesarios para compilar la extensión de Python psycopg2.

En Mac prueba lo siguiente:

- Abre la terminal de Mac
- Instala Homebrew que es un administrador de paquetes para macOS con este comando:

  `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`
- Usa dicho administrador de paquetes para instalar las bibliotecas de desarrollo de postgreSQL con este comando:

  `brew install postgresql`
- Una vez hecho esto, instala psycopg2 usando 'pip' en la misma terminal:
  `pip install psycopg2`

Antes de hacer todo eso te recomiendo desinstalar psycopg2 para 'empezar de 0' por así decirlo. Pruébalo y me cuentas.

Comment: Me sale command not found: brew y ya hice el primer paso

Comment: Quizas se deba a que no se agregó la ruta de Homebrew al archivo Path de tu sistema. Debes editar ese archivo. escribe open -e ~/.bash_profile para abrir el archivo. agrega la siguiente linea al final del mismo: export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH", guardalo y cierralo. Recarga el archivo escribiendo source ~/.bash_profile. Ahora prueba nuevamente a ejecutar el comando brew

Comment: Ahora sale The file /Users/jhonalmo23/.bash_profile does not exist.

Comment: asegurate de que existe ese archivo, por defecto no es visible, aqui tienes un tutorial post que trata sobre acceder a dicho archivo https://www.appleayuda.com/pregunta/84202/donde-se-encuentra-mi-bash_profile-mac-os-10105. Si el archivo no existe debes crearlo con el comando touch ~/.bash_profile

Comment: si ya existe modificalo y agrega la linea que te mostre en la respuesta, justo al final del archivo. Si no existe crealo y agrega dicha linea.

Comment: Ya lo cree y agrege la linea que me indicas, lo recargue y sigue presentando el error de que no encuentra brew

Comment: desinstala homebrew con el comando /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)" y vuelve a instalarlo nuevamente. Lo siento pero este tipo de errores es dificil de responder en este sitio

Comment: Encontre la causa del error y es que se instala en otra ruta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36657321/after-installing-homebrew-i-get-zsh-command-not-found-brew

Comment: pero me sigue generar error el pip install psycopg2

Comment: chequea esta pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420789/how-to-install-psycopg2-with-pip-on-python